# Trigger in Mysql to insert in a table or another

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to create a trigger that check a value in a json and select de table to insert

this is the example

```
delimiter #
CREATE TRIGGER tetsingschema.testingtirggerjson4 after insert ON tabla2
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
if (NEW.JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(nombre, '$.Name')) = 'Bart') then
INSERT INTO tabla3(nombre) values ('insert 1')
ELSE
INSERT INTO tabla2(nombre) values ('insert 2')
END if
INSERT INTO tabla2(nombre) values ('insert 2')
end
delimiter ;
```

i would like to know if this is possible

thanks a lot

Comment: You can't modify the same table that the trigger is attached to. So this won't work.

Comment: `NEW.JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(nombre, '$.Name'))` should be `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.nombre, '$.Name'))`

Comment: If `nombre` is suposed to be JSON, why are you trying to insert a simple string `insert 2` into it?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tetsingschema.testingtirggerjson4 
after insert ON tabla2
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
-- #1   if (NEW.JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(nombre, '$.Name')) = 'Bart') then
    if (JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.nombre, '$.Name')) = 'Bart') then
-- #2       INSERT INTO tabla3(nombre) values ('insert 1')
        INSERT INTO tabla3(nombre) values ('insert 1');
    ELSE
-- #3       INSERT INTO tabla2(nombre) values ('insert 2')
        INSERT INTO tabla3(nombre) values ('insert 2');
-- #4   END if
    END if;
-- #5   INSERT INTO tabla2(nombre) values ('insert 2')
    INSERT INTO tabla3(nombre) values ('insert 3');
end
```

#1 - `NEW` is used incorrectly.

#2..5 - each stmt must be terminated with `;`.

#3, 5 - debug tablename and debug message are fixed.